# C "argument is of type 'struct file *'"

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'm having trouble with a C concept. I'll be up-front, it's part of an assignment for my "Special Topics in Programming: Linux and C" class. I'm trying to make functions to write specific strings into a file (it's an accounting program, and the functions write page headers and footers), and I'm getting an error.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void writeToFile(FILE dataOut, char content[])
{
    fprintf(dataOut, content);
}

void main()
{
    FILE *dataOut;
    dataOut = fopen("testWrite.txt", "w");
    writeToFile(dataOut, "Leave no bars un-foo'd.");
}
```

The error message I get when I try to compile:

```
testWrite.c: In function ‘writeToFile’:
testWrite.c:5:2: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fprintf’
In file included from testWrite.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:357:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE * __restrict__’ but 
argument is of type ‘FILE’
testWrite.c: In function ‘main’:
testWrite.c:12:2: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘writeToFile’
testWrite.c:3:6: note: expected ‘FILE’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried manipulating pointers a bit, but it didn't change the error message. This code is an isolated example of what I want my code to do; if you would like to see the actual code, let me know. This just seemed like a clearer way to express what I was dealing with.

Comment: It seems as though you're jumping the gun, and making very basic mistakes as a result; Try learning about object types before you learn about functions.

Comment: If I was learning this on my own, I'd be taking it slowly, and learning more thoroughly; however, I'm on a time limit, and as such, sometimes I just need an answer to a question, without reading a textbook chapter (or the internet equivalent). And like I said in another comment, I was pretty sure I had tried the correct solution before I asked the question. I've got a decent handle on object types, but I assumed that there was something more to this than just pointers, so I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your function accept a pointer instead of the struct itself:

```
void writeToFile(FILE * dataOut, char content[])
```

Comment: You know, I could swear I tried that, but I guess not. Either way, I can accept your answer in ten minutes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are attempting to pass a pointer to a parameter that is expecting a non-pointer value.  The first parameter to `writeToFile` is `FILE` but the parameter `dataOut` is of type `FILE*`.  In order to make this work you need to make them both pointer values

```
void writeToFile(FILE* dataOut, char content[])
```